# Checking whether a date is earlier than the dates in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in an Excel file, Sheet A and Sheet B. In each, Column A is dates, and Column B is email addresses. Some of the dates in Sheet B are blank. In Sheet B, at the top of Column C, I have the following formula:

`=IF(LEN('Sheet B'!A2)=0,COUNTIF('Sheet A'!$B$2:$B$2642,'Sheet B'!B2),COUNTIFS('Sheet A'!$B$2:$B$2642,'Sheet B'!B2,'Sheet A'!$A$2:$A$2642,<='Sheet B'!A2))`

Excel is saying there's a problem with my formula. I'm 99% sure the problem is with how I wrote the very last condition in there: `'Sheet A'!$A$2:$A$2642,<='Sheet B'!A2`, specifically the part after the comma. Unfortunately, I have no idea why that's wrong or how to write it correctly. Any help?

Comment: Should be like this `=IF(LEN('Sheet B'!A2)=0,COUNTIF('Sheet A'!$B$2:$B$2642,'Sheet B'!B2),COUNTIFS('Sheet A'!$B$2:$B$2642,'Sheet B'!B2,'Sheet A'!$A$2:$A$2642,"<="&'Sheet B'!A2))`

Comment: `<=` this needs to be within quotes, `Logical operators` or `Boolean operators` when used within `COUNTIF`/`COUNTIFS`/`SUMIF`/`SUMIFS` Function as a criteria needs to be within the quotes.

Comment: you can shorten it to: `=COUNTIFS('Sheet A'!$B$2:$B$2642,'Sheet B'!B2,'Sheet A'!$A$2:$A$2642,"<="&IF(LEN('Sheet B'!A2)=0,1E+99,'Sheet B'!A2))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, what is the use of `1E+99` ? Sir, if possible could you share in `Answer` with an example.! Hope I'm not asking for too much.!

Comment: If that cell is empty then we want all of dates.  By creating an impossibly large number we would get all of them because all dates would be less than that number.  It removes the need of two separate countifs.  As far as answering, this is a typo question and should be closed as such, so I probably will not answer.@MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, much thanks, I saw sometime earlier on a query where you have shown in same way, but I dont remember the query nor i have bookmarked it. Still thanks a bunch Sir.!

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya , that did the trick!

Comment: @bkula thank you for sharing the feedback!

Comment: @ScottCraner I now understand that this post is based on a typo, though I had no idea that was a typo when I posted. I would love if you can explain ```1E+99``` so I'm able to understand and use your shortened version.

Comment: @bkula I did explain it. in my second comment.